# Installing fluentvalidation.webapi without nuget package manager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, fluentvalidation

Is there any way to install fluentvalidation.webapi without nuget or package manager console. When i install it through nuget/package-manager, it is changing the existing dll versions.

Is there any way i can just have fluentvalidation.webapi dll without changing or impacting any other dll or module?

Answer (score 1):

Download it directly from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.WebAPI/). There is a download link on the page.

Then extract the files. The .nupkg is basically a .zip file with a different file extension.

Comment: did that. but i an't find dll. i am able to see pdb though. any idea how copying the dll directly is different from installing it through nuget. nuget is doing some dependency changes which we want to avoid since we will have to retest everything.

Comment: If I download fluentvalidation.webapi 6.2.1.0 and unzip it the FluentValidation.WebApi.dll is in the lib\net45 directory right next to the FluentValidation.WebApi.pdb file. NuGet may be adding extra binding redirects to your app.config.

Comment: are these binding redirects necessary? can simply pasting these fluentvalidation.webapi dll be enough for me?

Comment: If your app works without the binding redirects then do not have to use them. Did you try just using the .dll directly?